# Como eu faço para fazer o echo "Sucesso" e "Falhou aparecerem abaixo do form?"

Tags: php

Como eu faço para fazer o echo "Sucesso" e "Falhou aparecerem abaixo do form?"

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","projeto");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);

  $inserir = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO teste(nome,senha) VALUES('$nome','$senha')");

  if ($inserir) {
    echo "Sucesso";
  }else{
    echo "Falhou";
  }
}

?>
```

```
<h1 id="nome">cadastro</h1>

<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome:">
  <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Crie uma nova senha:">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas com o PHP, uma maneira de fazer isso é criar uma div abaixo do form e uma variável com a mensagem da operação, ela deve ser definida antes do if que verifica se o `$_POST` existem, assim ela (`$msg`) passa a existir quando o form for chamado pela primeira vez ou seja evita um undefined variable ...

```
<?php
   $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","projeto");
   $msg = '';
   ...linhas omitidas
   $msg = $inserir ? 'sucesso' : 'falha';
   ...linhas omitidas  

   </form>
   <div id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado..